# Trying to uninstall imagemagick but all gems are installed in that directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick

I installed imagemagick in my rails app and now that I am trying to uninstall it, I realize all gems are located within that directory. As soon as I remove the directory it breaks my app. When I try to bundle install the gems again after removing the directory, it creates another imagemagick folder and puts all the gems in there. It seems imagemagick installed stuff all over my app. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Not sure which directory you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue.
The gems where installed into project/imagemagick folder

what I did was:

1. go to imagemagic/ruby/1.8/
2. cp -rvf * ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7@mygems/    (copied all gems from imagemagick folder into proper destination)
3. removed imagemagick folder
4. removed .bundle folder which was also created in my project folder

And that did the trick, however I do not know what will happen if I will update gem via bundler. And have no idea why it happened on first place!

Good Luck,

Grzegorz